# How to remove everything between two characters with sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file that contains a total of 482 lines i want to *remove ~~adt*~~* from. This is how the content looks like:

```
478|~~adt00000aa9~~~~adt0000000b~~14395189_p0.jpg
479|~~adt00000995~~44836628_p0.jpg
480|~~adt00000aae~~Miku_Collab_2_by_Luciaraio.jpg
```

I tried `sed 's/~~adt*~//' file > new_file` but it didn't remove everything.

How can i remove everything between the first and the last two ~~ signs?

Comment: Replace `*` by `.*`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that you want to remove `~~adt(something)~~` and that there may be `~~(something different)~~` on other lines (not shown in the question):

```
$ sed 's/~~adt[^~]*~~//g' file.in >file.out
```

For the given data, this will generate

```
478|14395189_p0.jpg
479|44836628_p0.jpg
480|Miku_Collab_2_by_Luciaraio.jpg
```

Changing the `adt` of the last line to `xxx`, the command generates

```
478|14395189_p0.jpg
479|44836628_p0.jpg
480|~~xxx00000aae~~Miku_Collab_2_by_Luciaraio.jpg
```

The pattern `~~adt[^~]*~~` will match all occurrences of `~~adt` followed by any number of characters that are not `~`, and then `~~` again.  The `/g` at the end will ensure that all such matches on every line are removed.

Comment: Using the above useful concept this one removes parenthesis and everything inside:  sed 's/([^)]*)//g file.in >file.out

Answer (score 1):

`adt*` means `a` followed by `d` followed by any number of `t`'s including 0.

Dot matches any character, so use

```
~~adt.*~
```

To match `~~adt` followed by any number (including 0) of characters, followed by `~`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
sed 's/~.*~//' file > file_new
```

Output will:

```
478|14395189_p0.jpg
479|44836628_p0.jpg
480|Miku_Collab_2_by_Luciaraio.jpg
```